# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://mms.shaparak.ir/merchant/webService/writeExternalRequest `400 Bad Request

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, guzzle

I am trying to make a post request to a web service. I am using laravel 8 and "guzzlehttp/guzzle" ^7.0.1
the problem is that sometimes it works fine but sometimes it returns the below error:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error:
> POST https://mms.shaparak.ir/merchant/webService/writeExternalRequest resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:
> <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-fam (truncated...)
> in file C:\xampp\htdocs\milyoona\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113

here is my service where I make the request :

```
<?php


namespace App\Services\ShaparakTerminalRequest;


use App\Nova\Models\User\Terminal;
use App\Nova\Models\User\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian;


class ShaparakTerminalRequestService
{
    public static function canSendRequest(Terminal $terminal)
{
    $user = $terminal->user;
    if (!$user->addresses->first()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($user->national_code and $user->birth_date and $user->mobile and $user->first_name_fa and $user->last_name_fa and $user->first_name_en and $user->last_name_en and $user->father_name_en) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!$user->user_type) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($user->register_date and $user->com_name_fa and $user->com_name_en) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static function shaparakDate($time)
{
    $time = (new Jalalian(substr($time, 0, 4), substr($time, 5, 2), substr($time, 8, 2)))->getTimestamp();
    $time = str_pad($time, 13, "0");
    return intval($time);
}

private static function shaparakBirthDate($time)
{
    $time = (new Jalalian(substr($time, 0, 4), substr($time, 5, 2), substr($time, 8, 2)))->getTimestamp();
    $time = str_pad($time, 12, "0");
    return intval($time);
}

private static function ibanBuilder(User $user)
{
    $iban = [];
    foreach ($user->ibans as $item) {
        array_push($iban, ["merchantIban" => $item['iban'], "description" => $item['label']]);
    }
    return $iban;
}


public static function requestTracker(\App\Models\Shaparak\ShaparakTerminalRequest $request)
{
    $data = [
        'trackingNumberPsps' => [
            $request->tracking_number
        ]
    ];
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://mms.shaparak.ir/merchant/webService/readRequestCartableWithFilter', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic YWxhMV9wZjpNaWx5b29uYTFxYXohUUFa',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($data, true)
    ]);

    $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    $request->update([
        'request_response' => $response[0]['merchant'],
        'status' => $response[0]['status']
    ]);


    if ($response[0]['status'] == 14) {
        if ($request['request_body'][0]['requestType'] == 13) {
            $request->user->update([
                "first_name_fa" => $request['request_response']['firstNameFa'],
                "last_name_fa" => $request['request_response']['lastNameFa'],
                "father_name_fa" => $request['request_response']['fatherNameFa'],
                "birth_crtfct_number" => $request['request_response']['birthCrtfctNumber'],
                "birth_crtfct_serial" => $request['request_response']['birthCrtfctSerial'],
                "birth_crtfct_series_letter" => $request['request_response']['birthCrtfctSeriesLetter'] + 1,
                "birth_crtfct_series_number" => $request['request_response']['birthCrtfctSeriesNumber'],
                "gender" => $request['request_response']['gender'],
                "shaparak_verified_at" =>jdate(Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d')),
            ]);
        } elseif ($request['request_body'][0]['requestType'] == 5) {
            $terminal = $request->terminal;
            $terminal->update([
                'shaparak_verified_at' => jdate(Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d')),
                'active' => 1
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $request;
}


private static function userBuilder($user, $address)
{
    if ($user->user_type == 0) {
        return [
            "firstNameFa" => null,
            "lastNameFa" => null,
            "fatherNameFa" => null,
            "firstNameEn" => $user->first_name_en,
            "lastNameEn" => $user->last_name_en,
            "fatherNameEn" => $user->father_name_en,
            "gender" => $user->gender,
            "birthDate" => self::shaparakBirthDate($user->birth_date),
            "registerDate" => null,
            "nationalCode" => $user->national_code,
            "registerNumber" => null,
            "comNameEn" => null,
            "merchantType" => $user->user_type,
            "residencyType" => $user->residency_type,
            "vitalStatus" => $user->vital_status,
            "birthCrtfctNumber" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSerial" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSeriesLetter" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSeriesNumber" => null,
            "nationalLegalCode" => null,
            "commercialCode" => null,
            "countryCode" => null,
            "foreignPervasiveCode" => null,
            "passportNumber" => null,
            "passportExpireDate" => null,
            "description" => "",
            "telephoneNumber" => substr_replace($address->phone, "-", 3, 0),
            "cellPhoneNumber" => $user->mobile,
            "emailAddress" => "iman.rjb@gmail.com",
            "webSite" => "milyoona.com",
            "fax" => "",
            "merchantIbans" => self::ibanBuilder($user),
            "merchantOfficers" => null,
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            "firstNameFa" => null,
            "lastNameFa" => null,
            "fatherNameFa" => null,
            "firstNameEn" => null,
            "lastNameEn" => null,
            "fatherNameEn" => null,
            "gender" => null,
            "birthDate" => null,
            "registerDate" => $user->register_date,
            "nationalCode" => null,
            "registerNumber" => null,
            "comNameEn" => $user->com_name_en,
            "merchantType" => $user->user_type,
            "residencyType" => $user->residency_type,
            "vitalStatus" => $user->vital_status,
            "birthCrtfctNumber" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSerial" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSeriesLetter" => null,
            "birthCrtfctSeriesNumber" => null,
            "nationalLegalCode" => $user->national_legal_code,
            "commercialCode" => null,
            "countryCode" => null,
            "foreignPervasiveCode" => null,
            "passportNumber" => null,
            "passportExpireDate" => null,
            "description" => "",
            "telephoneNumber" => substr_replace($address->phone, "-", 3, 0),
            "cellPhoneNumber" => $user->mobile,
            "emailAddress" => "iman.rjb@gmail.com",
            "webSite" => "milyoona.com",
            "fax" => "",
            "merchantIbans" => self::ibanBuilder($user),
            "merchantOfficers" =>
                [
                    "firstNameFa" => null,
                    "lastNameFa" => null,
                    "fatherNameFa" => null,
                    "firstNameEn" => $user->first_name_en,
                    "lastNameEn" => $user->last_name_en,
                    "fatherNameEn" => $user->father_name_en,
                    "gender" => $user->gender,
                    "birthDate" => self::shaparakBirthDate($user->birth_date),
                    "nationalCode" => $user->national_code,
                    "residencyType" => $user->residency_type,
                    "vitalStatus" => $user->vital_status,
                    "birthCrtfctNumber" => null,
                    "birthCrtfctSerial" => null,
                    "birthCrtfctSeriesLetter" => null,
                    "birthCrtfctSeriesNumber" => null,
                    "countryCode" => null,
                    "foreignPervasiveCode" => null,
                    "passportNumber" => null,
                    "passportExpireDate" => null,
                    "description" => "",
                ],
            "updateAction" => null,
        ];
    }

}

private static function shopBuilder($terminal, $address)
{
    return [
        "farsiName" => $terminal->name_fa,
        "englishName" => $terminal->name_en,
        "telephoneNumber" => substr_replace($address->phone, "-", 3, 0),
        "postalCode" => $address->zip_code,
        "businessCertificateNumber" => null,
        "certificateExpiryDate" => null,
        "description" => null,
        "businessCategoryCode" => $terminal->jobCategory->code,
        "businessSubCategoryCode" => '0',
        "certificateIssueDate" => null,
        "rentalExpiryDate" => null,
        "rentalContractNumber" => "",
        "address" => null,
        "countryCode" => "IR",
        "provinceCode" => null,
        "cityCode" => null,
        "ownershipType" => 0,
        "businessType" => 2,
        "etrustCertificateType" => 0,
        "etrustCertificateIssueDate" => null,
        "etrustCertificateExpiryDate" => null,
        "emailAddress" => 'info@' . $terminal->website . '.com',
        "websiteAddress" => $terminal->website,
        "taxPayerCode" => '000000000000'
    ];
}

private static function contractBuilder($terminal)
{

    return [
        "contractDate" => self::shaparakDate(jdate(Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d'))),
        "expiryDate" => self::shaparakDate(jdate(Carbon::now()->addYears(5)->format('Y/m/d'))),
        "serviceStartDate" => self::shaparakDate(jdate(Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d'))),
        "contractNumber" => $terminal->terminal,
        "description" => null,
        "updateAction" => 0
    ];
}


private static function acceptorBuilder(Terminal $terminal)
{

    $inn = '581672111';
    $facilitatorAcceptorCode = '992180002039591';


    $psp = $terminal->irankishes->first();

    return [
        [
            "iin" => $inn,
            "acceptorCode" => $psp->acceptor,
            "facilitatorAcceptorCode" => $facilitatorAcceptorCode,
            "acceptorType" => 2,
            "cancelable" => "false",
            "refundable" => "false",
            "blockable" => "false",
            "chargeBackable" => "false",
            "settledSeparately" => "false",
            "allowScatteredSettlement" => 0,
            "acceptCreditCardTransaction" => "true",
            "allowIranianProductsTrx" => "true",
            "allowKaraCardTrx" => "false",
            "allowGoodsBasketTrx" => "false",
            "allowFoodSecurityTrx" => "false",
            "allowJcbCardTrx" => "false",
            "allowUpiCardTrx" => "false",
            "allowVisaCardTrx" => "false",
            "allowMasterCardTrx" => "false",
            "allowAmericanExpressTrx" => "false",
            "allowOtherInternationaCardsTrx" => "false",
            "description" => "",
            "shaparakSettlementIbans" => [
                "IR670560081682902953030001"
            ],
            "terminals" => [[
                "sequence" => self::generateSequenceNo(),
                "terminalNumber" => $psp->terminal,
                "serialNumber" => null,
                "setupDate" => self::shaparakDate(jdate(Carbon::now()->format('Y/m/d'))),
                "terminalType" => 1,
                "hardwareBrand" => null,
                "hardwareModel" => null,
                "accessAddress" => $terminal->website,
                "accessPort" => "443",
                "callbackAddress" => $terminal->website,
                "callbackPort" => "443",
                "description" => ""
            ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}


public static function terminalCreate(Terminal $terminal)
{
    $psp = $terminal->irankishes->first();
    if ($psp->status != 0) {
        return response()->json(['message' => responseMessage(27)], 200);
    }

    $user = $terminal->user;
    $address = $user->addresses->first();
    $data = [[
        "trackingNumberPsp" => "ML" . time(),
        "requestType" => *,
        "merchant" => self::userBuilder($user, $address),
        "relatedMerchants" => null,
        "contract" => self::contractBuilder($terminal),
        "pspRequestShopAcceptors" => [
            [
                'shop' => self::shopBuilder($terminal, $address),
                'acceptors' => self::acceptorBuilder($terminal)
            ]
        ],
        "description" => null,
    ]];


    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://mms.shaparak.ir/merchant/webService/writeExternalRequest', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic *********************',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($data, true)
    ]);

    $request = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    $shaparak_terminal_request = new \App\Models\Shaparak\ShaparakTerminalRequest();
    $shaparak_terminal_request->user_id = $user->id;
    $shaparak_terminal_request->tracking_number = $request[0]['trackingNumberPsp'];
    $shaparak_terminal_request->shaparak_tracking_number = $request[0]['trackingNumber'];
    $shaparak_terminal_request->request_body = $data;
    $shaparak_terminal_request->success = $request[0]['success'];
    if (!$request[0]['success']) {
        $shaparak_terminal_request->error = $request[0]['requestRejectionReasons'];
        $shaparak_terminal_request->status = 5;
    } else {
        $shaparak_terminal_request->status = 12;
    }
    $shaparak_terminal_request->save();
    if ($shaparak_terminal_request->success) {
        self::requestTracker($shaparak_terminal_request);
    }

    return $shaparak_terminal_request;
}

private static function generateSequenceNo ()
{
    $length = 20;
    $count = 1;
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $sequenceNo = '';
    for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
        if ($sequenceNo !== '') {
            $sequenceNo .= '-';
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $sequenceNo .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
    }
    return $sequenceNo;
}
}
```

`terminalCreate()` method makes the request.
and here I'm calling the service :

> ```
> public function test()
> ```

```
   {
       return ShaparakTerminalRequest::terminalCreate(Terminal::whereWebsite('sauer.biz')->first());
   }
```

Am I doing sth wrong? please guide.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem?